# regarding wordpress to show single widget

Tags: wordpress

Is there any API function which display single widget anywhere in our template by passing widget id or name something.

I just wanna show Tag Cloud widget alone in ma home page. front-page.php

Thanks,

Edvin :)

Answer (score 1):

[`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) allows you to display a single widget. You do not have to configure it first in the administration area.

```
the_widget(
    'WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud',
    array(
        'title' => 'Popular tags',
    ),
    array(
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks but most of the 3rd party tag cloud plugin don't have class names so it won't for all widgets

Comment: since i cant answer my own with my 20 reputation point here is the answer <?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-cirrus]"); ?>

Comment: Im using 3D tag cloud name wp-cirrus

Comment: @Edvin: In that case, looking at the code, you could also do `<?php echo wpcirrusInit( true, array() ); ?>`, which is what the shortcode handler does.